AWS API Gatweay Gateway Response How do you return input body properties in when BAD_REQUEST_BODY is triggered?
I would to get AWS Api Gateway Gateway Response to return one of the input body properties, this can be done in a workaround during integration response.
APIGW integration response with input body, workaround (This is working and is an example of something I thought I could do in Gateway responses.)
First set the override in request template:
{
    "application/json": """
#set($context.requestOverride.path.body = $input.body)
#set( $body = $input.body )
#set( $bodyobj = $util.parseJson($body) )
#set( $quote = '"' )
{{
    "DeliveryStreamName": "{delivery_stream_name}",
    "Record": {{
        "Data": $body"
    }}
}}""".format(
        delivery_stream_name=delivery_stream_name,
    ),
}

Then in response template:
{
    "statusCode": "200",
    "responseTemplates": {
        "application/json": """
#set( $body = $context.requestOverride.path.body )
#set( $bodyobj = $util.parseJson($body) )
#set( $quote = '"' )
{{
"cola": {pks},
"colB": true,
"colC": "$context.requestTimeEpoch"
}}""".format(
            pks=json.dumps(
                {
                    x: f"$bodyobj.{x}"
                    for x in ['colA', 'colB']
                },
                indent=4,
            )
        ),
    },
}

What I am trying to do in my current Gateway Response. I attempted the $context.requestOverride but I cannot seem to access this in the gateway response.

{
    "statusCode": "400",
    "responseTemplates": {
        "application/json": """
#set( $body = $context.requestOverride.path.body )
#set( $bodyobj = $util.parseJson($body) )
#set( $quote = '"' )
{{
"colA": {pks},
"colB": false,
"errors": [
    $context.error.responseType,
    $context.error.validationErrorString
]
}}""".format(
            pks=json.dumps(
                {
                    x: f"$bodyobj.{x}"
                    for x in ['colA','colB']
                },
                indent=4,
            )
        ),
    },

